# How to count all likes no matter how many times a post is shared and reshared?

Tags: facebook-like

I want to be able to count the total number of likes for a post or photo no matter how many times the post has been shared and reshared.

I want to know how popular a post is across the whole Facebook Universe.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not fully possible, for these reasons:

1. Facebook does not indicate via the API whether a post is a re-share
   of another post (there is no "via" property on Post objects, in
   other words). Nor is there a property that indicates where or how
   many times a particular post has been re-shared.
2. Many posts on Facebook use privacy settings set by the user creating the post, and
   this applies to re-shared stories as well. Your app has access to
   whatever its users give it permission to read, but that does not
   grant it access to the feeds of all users on Facebook.

At most, you could theoretically do this (although I am not sure if there are other limitations in place to prevent this):
Search all PUBLIC posts on Facebook, for text that matches the text in the post you want to track. (see the documentation under "Searching" here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Aggregate the Likes for all of these posts. Just understand that this is only the subset of posts that your app is capable of viewing.